# haskell non-exhaustive patterns missing

Tags: haskell

I'm getting following error for the below, I assume all the recursive cases, What is missing ?

```
Prelude> product [] =1
Prelude> product (x:xs) =x * product xs
Prelude> product [1,2,3]
*** Exception: <interactive>:48:1-30: Non-exhaustive patterns in function product
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHCi processes each line separately, so you have defined a function

```
product [] = 1
```

and then shadowed `product` by defining a new function

```
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

To fix this, you can use `:{` and `:}` for a multiline block:

```
:{
product [] = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
:}
```

or, and this is what I would recommend, put your function definitions in a file and load them in GHCi.

Comment: or you can write it as one line: `product [] = 1; product (x:xs) = x * product xs`

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to turn on warnings with `-Wall`. Doing so, here, would also hint at the fact that each definition is considered separately.

```
> :set -Wall
> product [] = 1

<interactive>:2:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘product’: Patterns not matched: (_:_)
> product (x:xs) = x * product xs

<interactive>:3:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘product’: Patterns not matched: []
```

Indeed, note how the last warning complaints about `[]` not being matched, showing that the first definition `product []` was ignored.